# ajax success not displaying in div

Tags: ajax

Hi i try to display the ajax success in div. But its not displaying. when i click on start exam the success was just blink and disappear. my code is here

```
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#qp').click(function(){

             var roll='<?php echo $roll; ?>';
             var branch=roll.substring(6,8);
             $.ajax({
                 url:'test4.php',
                 type:'post',
                 data:'br='+branch+'&rno='+roll,
                 success:function(result)
                 {
                   $('#qns').html(result);
                 }
             });

           });

        });
    </script>
   </head>
  <body>
      <div>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="" id="qp">Start Exam</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
       <div id="qns">

        </div>
     </head>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: try to remove href from start time

Comment: yah success my friend thanks alot